# How to Loop Datareader and create DataTable in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

First of all let me thank those people that answered my previous questions. You guys are Awesome!!!

Here is my question:
I like to query my sql server Stored procedure and return a datareader. However I want to create a Table out of it. That table I will use to load excel using the new Powershell OpenXML commandlets. The code fails when I try to build the DataTable. I don't think I am loding the new-object "System.Object[]" correctly. Here is what I got so far:

```
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=localhost;database=Demo;Integrated Security=sspi"
$sqlConnection.Open()

#Create a command object
$sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC Demo.usp_GetTableValueParameter_Data"

#Execute the Command
$sqlReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

#Parse the records

$sqlReader | &{ begin{$values = new-object "System.Object[]" $sqlReader["Name"], $sqlReader["Level_Desc"], $sqlReader["Level"]} process {$_.GetValues($values); $datatable.Rows.Add($values)}}

##$datatable | format-table -autosize

# Close the database connection
$sqlConnection.Close()

#STARTING OPENXML PROCESS
#----------------------------
$xlsFile = "C:\Temp\Data.xlsx"
$datatable | Export-OpenXmlSpreadSheet -OutputPath $xlsFile  -InitialRow 3
```

Answer (score 17):

Translating [Mladen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184893/how-to-loop-datareader-and-create-datatable-in-powershell/1184967#1184967) into PowerShell is pretty straight forward:

```
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=localhost;database=Demo;Integrated Security=sspi"
$sqlConnection.Open()

#Create a command object
$sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC Demo.usp_GetTableValueParameter_Data"

#Execute the Command
$sqlReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$DataTable.Load($SqlReader)

# Close the database connection
$sqlConnection.Close()

#STARTING OPENXML PROCESS
#----------------------------
$xlsFile = "C:\Temp\Data.xlsx"
$datatable | Export-OpenXmlSpreadSheet -OutputPath $xlsFile  -InitialRow 3
```

However, if you just need a DataTable back, you don't need to call ExecuteReader on the command, you could create a DataAdapter and use that to fill the DataTable:

```
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=localhost;database=Demo;Integrated Security=sspi"
$sqlConnection.Open()

#Create a command object
$sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC Demo.usp_GetTableValueParameter_Data"

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlcommand
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | out-null

# Close the database connection
$sqlConnection.Close()

$datatable = $dataset.Tables[0]  

#STARTING OPENXML PROCESS
#----------------------------
$xlsFile = "C:\Temp\Data.xlsx"
$datatable | Export-OpenXmlSpreadSheet -OutputPath $xlsFile  -InitialRow 3
```

Answer (score 3):

i have no clue how to do this in powershell but in .net you do it like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(yourSqlReader);
```